# Profile isn't updating or updates aren't showing up in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to make a page in django where users can look at their profiles and edit and save the changes, but everytime i click on the save button, nothing happens and when I refresh the page, the information doesn't get updated. What am I doing wrong?

This is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,null= True ,on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(null = True, blank= True)
    first = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    last = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    mobile_number = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length= 500, null= True)
    postal = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first
```

This is my forms.py:

```
class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = '__all__'
    exclude = ['user']
    widgets = {
        'profile_pic': forms.FileInput()
    }
```

This is my views.py:

```
@login_required(login_url='Login')
def Profile(request):
    profile = request.user.profile
    form = ProfileForm(instance=profile)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILE, instance=profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reversed('Profile'))
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

This is my template:

```
<div class="col-lg middle middle-profile-con">

        <div class="img-cir profile-img">
            <img src="{{request.user.profile.profile_pic.url}}" alt="" width="100px" height="100px" class="pro-img">

        </div>

        <form method='POST' action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="">
                <p class="my-name-pro">{{request.user.profile.first}}
                    <p>
                        <p class="my-email-id-pro">{{request.user.profile.email}} <br> {{form.profile_pic}}</p>

            </div>
            <div class="">
                <div class="pro-fn-div">
                    <label class="pro-fn-label">First name</label>
                    <div class="pro-fn-input"> {{form.first}} </div>
                </div>

                <div class="pro-ln-div">
                    <label class="pro-fn-label">Last name</label>
                    <div class="pro-fn-input"> {{form.last}} </div>
                </div>

                <div class="pro-email-div">
                    <label class="pro-fn-label">Email ID</label>
                    <div class="pro-fn-input"> {{form.email}} </div>
                </div>

                <div class="pro-pn-div">
                    <label class="pro-fn-label">Phone Number</label>
                    <div class="pro-fn-input"> {{form.mobile_number}} </div>
                </div>

                <div class="pro-lo-div">
                    <label class="pro-fn-label">Location</label>
                    <div class="pro-fn-input"> {{form.location}} </div>
                </div>

                <div class="pro-pc-div">
                    <label class="pro-fn-label">Postal Code</label>
                    <div class="pro-fn-input"> {{form.postal}} </div>
                </div>

                <button type="button" name="Update Information" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm pro-btn-save">Save Changes</button>

        </form>

        </div>
```

I don't understand where I'm going wrong. Do I need to add something in the template? Maybe in the save button or something?

Comment: Where is your urls.py ?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to register your url so for example :

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('profile/', views.profile, name="profile"),
]
```

In your **template**, edit your form

```
<form method='POST' action="{% url 'profile' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Note that variable in Python are lowercase, following the convention is best